# Why does reducing the contact area increase traction on ice instead of causing slippage?

Tags: friction, ice

I mean treads on tires, studs and snow chains. To begin with, I would think that reducing the area will increase the pressure causing the ice to melt and make it slippery as is the case with ice skating. Secondly, it seems to me that reduced area will also cause a greater normal force, thus making it easier to exceed the maximum static friction and switch into undesirable kinetic friction.

Answer (score 2):

First, it is my understanding that narrower tires can have better traction on snow because they may be able to cut through ice and snow better and potentially make contact with more of the higher coefficient of friction road surface.

Second, the normal force equals that portion of the weight of the vehicle supported by the drive wheel, which would be unchanged by reducing the contact area (using a narrower tire). So the maximum static friction force, $uN$, would theoretically be unchanged.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understood my misconception about the normal force, but the first part does not make sense to me.

Comment: Regarding the first part, think about trying to cut something with a knife. The sharper the knife (the narrower the blade) the deeper it penetrates something for the same applied force because that force is applied over a smaller area. Now consider the tire. It can cut through the snow better if it is narrower because the same force is more concentrated. If it cuts through enough ice to reach the road surface where the coefficient of static friction is greater than the ice, traction is improved.

Answer (score 1):

To add to other answers, less contact surface means more pressure, which reduces the melting point of the ice helping it to cut through it and be more stable.

You can perform an experiment by passing a thread with the use of considerable force through an ice slab quickly. This happens because pressure reduces melting point causing it to melt. The slab rejoins upon the passing of the thread as the pressure is released causing the melting point to increase and freezing the slab again.

Comment: Wny is what you described not the case with ice skates?

Comment: I guess I see now: the blades of the skates are pushed along the the cutting, not perpendicularly against it

Answer (score 0):

About the area of the contact surface:

Your reasoning is applicable in the case of tyres for racing cars. [Racing slicks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racing_slick) have more grip than tyres with grooves.

Racing car tyres are made of a much softer compound than daily use cars. As the compound comes in contact with the surface it deforms with the texture of the surface. Also, the hard surface is tearing off compound all the time. The tyres are so soft they are shredded.

The purpose of studs and chains is to *cut* into the surface (ice or icy snow). The most extreme example would be ice speedway. I assume that over the course of a racing day the ice is being shredded all the time and that at the end of the day very little ice is left. So this case the surface is shredded.